# Overriding new button in List view to point to custom apex page

Tags: visualforce, button-overrides, apexpage

I want to override my new action (button on listview) for a custom object with a link to a custom apex page. 
I have created an apex page with the following attributes :

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false" sidebar="false" applyHtmlTag="false" applyBodyTag="false" docType="html-5.0"  controller="TestController">
```

However when I go in my custom object > Button, Links and Actions > New > Edit>Salesforce Classic Override>Visualforce page 
the picklist doesnt display my visualForce page.

What should I do to override my new action in the listview to link to my custom apex page ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use a Visualforce page to override a list button or create a new list button, you must use both a `standardController` and `recordSetVar` attribute. This tells Salesforce that this page understands a list of records. Your controller will now operate as an "extension" (see the `extensions` attribute), instead of a controller, and so will need a new constructor that accepts a single parameter, an `ApexPages.StandardSetController`.

```
<apex:page 
    showHeader="false" 
    standardStylesheets="false" 
    sidebar="false" 
    applyHtmlTag="false" 
    applyBodyTag="false" 
    docType="html-5.0"  
    standardController="Account"
    recordSetVar="accounts" 
    extensions="TestController">
  ...
</apex:page>
```

---

```
public class TestController {
  public TestController(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller) {
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: The phrase "Your controller will need a new constructor to support the page." should probably be re-worded to show that the Ops controller is converted to an extension. Just a small bit of clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Only Visualforce pages that use the standard controller for the object will appears  and you can use it. extend the action by use extension attribute.

So if you need to use to page in action you can do like below:

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" 
           standardStylesheets="false" 
           sidebar="false" 
           applyHtmlTag="false" 
           applyBodyTag="false" 
           docType="html-5.0" 
           StandardController="objectname__c" 
           extensions="TestController">
    ........
</apex:page>
```

[refer this link](https://developer.secure.force.com/cookbook/recipe/overriding-a-standard-button)

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post with any clarifications. That's not what comments are for.