# Custom Javascript Button on List View Help

Tags: javascript, custom-button, list-view

Happy Friday!

Looking to see if the following is possible using only Javascript.
I have two Custom Objects - Obj1 & Obj2 (both have child relationship to Account).

Using a List View Button on Obj1, create new records in Obj2 (based on selected records in List View).  Ideally this would create unique records by Account.  For example, if 5 records were selected associated to 3 Accounts in total, only 3 records would be created in Obj2.

I have looked for posts on similar inquiries but haven't found anything matching this use case with a confirmed answer if it's even possible or not.

Any help/guidance/programming help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the list view button with the vf page and there you can have your logic based on selected records.
Here is the link to another question where you would get help how to create such list view button :

[Overriding new button in List view to point to custom apex page](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/246661/overriding-new-button-in-list-view-to-point-to-custom-apex-page/246664)

Comment: Thanks for the response - Wouldn't this then require Apex coding from the Visualforce page?  I'm looking to see if this is possible using only Javascript.

Comment: Yes. It will require apex coding